# Matplotlib memory leak in Ubuntu, but not in Windows 10

Tags: matplotlib, multiprocessing

I have a code that reads images from folders and annotates the images. I have about 10K images of size 3K x 3K. I apply cell detection, and I put an annotation on the images. For simplicity, I in the snapshot code provided below, the code generates a random image and random annotations with X and Y location.

The code works fine, in windows 10, with python 3.6 for both multiprocessing and without multiprocessing. However, when I submit to the HPC server with ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.6, I am getting memory error with Matplotlib. I have tried the following, but no luck in resolving the problem.

```
* plt.close(fig)
* plt.figure().clear()
* plt.clf()
* plt.close()
```

'''

```
import os

import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

import pandas as pd

import multiprocessing as mp

import numpy as np

import seaborn as sns

sns.set_palette('bright')

def mark_points(im, df, file_name):
    # this code put scatter plot on the image and saves the the figure
    dpi = 100
    height, width, nbands = im.shape

    # What size does the figure need to be in inches to fit the image?
    fig_size = width / float(dpi), height / float(dpi)

    # Create a figure of the right size with one axes that takes up the full figure
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=fig_size)
    ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])

    # Hide spines, ticks, etc.
    ax.axis('off')

    # Display the image.
    ax.imshow(im, interpolation='nearest')
    sns.scatterplot(x='X',
                    y='Y',
                    data=df,
                    hue='Class',
                    ax=ax,
                    s=2,
                    edgecolor=None,
                    legend=False)
        
    ax.set(xlim=[0, width], ylim=[height, 0], aspect=1)

    # save image with cell annotation
    fig.savefig(file_name, dpi=dpi, transparent=True)
    # plt.close(fig)
    plt.figure().clear()
    plt.clf()
    plt.close()


def annotate_images(output_dir,
                    process_num):
    # create an image and random X and Y location for annotation
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
    
    for j in range(10000):
        
        # this approximately the size of image I am processing
        im_height, im_width = 3000, 3000
        # print('{}'.format(process_num))
        
        file_name = 'my_file_name_{}.jpg'.format(process_num)
        output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, file_name)
        
        # generate dataframe with data to plot
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['X', 'Y', 'Class'])
        num_points = 20000
        df['X'] = np.random.randint(0, im_width, size=(num_points), dtype='int32').tolist()
        df['Y'] = np.random.randint(0, im_height, size=(num_points), dtype='int32').tolist()
        
        classes_ = ['A', 'B', 'C']
        df['Class'] = [classes_[np.random.randint(0, 3)] for _ in range(num_points)]
        
        # generate a random image
        im = np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(im_height, im_width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

        mark_points(im=im, df=df, file_name=output_file)


def run(output_dir,
        num_processes=1,
        multi_process=False
        ):
    
    # number of folders
    n = 100
    for i in range(n):
        if multi_process is True:
            processes = [
                mp.Process(target=annotate_images, args=(output_dir, process_num)) for process_num in range(num_processes)]

            print('{} processes created'.format(num_processes))

            # Run processes
            for p in processes:
                p.start()

            # Exit the completed processes
            for p in processes:
                p.join()
            print('All Processes finished!!!')
        else:
            annotate_images(output_dir=output_dir,
                            process_num=0
                            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    num_processes = 4
    multi_process = True
    
    home_dir = r'Output'

    for i in range(3):
        params = dict(output_dir=home_dir,
                      num_processes=num_processes,
                      multi_process=multi_process)
        run(**params)
```

'''

**Error message**

```
image_annotate_cells.py:44: RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).
  plt.figure().clear()
image_annotate_cells.py:22: RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened. Figures created through the pyplot interface (`matplotlib.pyplot.figure`) are retained until explicitly closed and may consume too much memory. (To control this warning, see the rcParam `figure.max_open_warning`).
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=fig_size)
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "image_annotate_cells.py", line 74, in annotate_images
    mark_points(im=im, df=df, file_name=output_file)
  File "image_annotate_cells.py", line 42, in mark_points
    fig.savefig(file_name, dpi=dpi, transparent=True)
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 2203, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2126, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py", line 358, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 584, in print_jpg
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 393, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1736, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 137, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2630, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 137, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 894, in draw
    Collection.draw(self, renderer)
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 38, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 369, in draw
    self._offset_position)
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/path.py", line 197, in vertices
    @property
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image_annotate_cells.py", line 124, in <module>
    run(**params)
  File "image_annotate_cells.py", line 97, in run
    p.join()
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 124, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 50, in wait
    return self.poll(os.WNOHANG if timeout == 0.0 else 0)
  File "/home/DMP/DUDMP/COPAINGE/yhagos/.conda/envs/tf2cpu/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 28, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: I’d specify the figure handle when you call close.

Comment: Thank you Jody. I have already tried **plt.close(fig)** as well and it didn't solve the problem.